# Read multiple rows from file, rows numbers given in another file

Tags: shell, awk

I know how to read the nth row from a file using awk:

```
awk 'NR == 10' myfile.txt
```

and it works fine. Now I need to read multiple rows from this file, and rows numbers are given in another file `myrows.txt`:

```
10
15
25
100
```

is it possible do do something like this:

```
cat myrows.txt | awk 'NR == ?how?' myfile.txt
```

or do I need a loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this awk:

```
awk 'FNR==NR {a[$0]; next} FNR in a' myrows.txt myfile.txt
```

**Explanation:**

```
FNR==NR  # for first file populate an array `a` with line numbers as key
next     # keep reading 1st file till EOF is reached
FNR in a # print record from 2nd file if current line # in 2nd file is in array a
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sed` as well:

```
sed -n "$(sed 's/$/p;/' rows.txt)" myfile.txt
```

The inner `sed` commands creates the following script

```
10p;
15p;
25p;
100p;
```

... which would get executed by the outer `sed` command.

Btw, I would prefer the `awk` solution from @anubhava. It looks much more cleaner. However, both commands are doing the same.

Comment: I think I prefer an awk only solution, but this is also a nice idea... thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can use also while loop:

```
while read line
do
  awk "NR == $line" myfile.txt
done < "myrows.txt"
```

Comment: I think I'm going to accept anubhava's answer because it only uses awk, but this is a nice and simple idea, thank you